# CDM Nuget Packages

Tags: c#, tfs, azure-devops, azure-data-factory, common-data-service

I am looking to create ADF pipeline to load data to powerapps entity using CDM. I have exported the data from powerapps to ADLS. I was following this article:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/common-data-service/export-to-data-lake-data-adf

So, for creating a manifest file a c# code is provided along with few CDM nuget packages. These are in TFS/Devops for which i dont have access.
Path: https://commondatamodel.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/CDM/nuget/v3/index.json

Error:

```json
{
    "$id": "1",
    "innerException": null,
    "message": "TF400813: The user '72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47\\xyz@abc.com' is not authorized to access this resource.",
    "typeName": "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.UnauthorizedRequestException, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server",
    "typeKey": "UnauthorizedRequestException",
    "errorCode": 0,
    "eventId": 3000
}
```

Can you guide me on how to download these packages or create manifest file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can you guide me on how to download these packages or create manifest file?

I am afraid you have to use another account that has permission to access that CDM feed.

According to the [Azure roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/common-data-service/export-to-data-lake-data-adf#azure-roles):

> **The user account that's used to sign in to Azure must be a member of
> the contributor or owner role, or an administrator of the Azure
> subscription**. To view the permissions that you have in the
> subscription, go to the Azure portal, select your username in the
> upper-right corner, select ..., and then select My permissions. If you
> have access to multiple subscriptions, select the appropriate one. To
> create and manage child resources for Data Factory in the Azure
> portal—including datasets, linked services, pipelines, triggers, and
> integration runtimes—you must belong to the Data Factory Contributor
> role at the resource group level or above.

As test, My account is also unable to access the feed directly：

[image]

But my manager (with higher authority) can directly access that feed:

[image]

So, you could try to install/download those packages with another account that has permission to access that CDM feed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have admin role in my azure subscription. I am using the same credentials to access these nuget packages even then i get the same error. Can you guide me on any other ways? 

Also, if you can you download the nuget packages and share it across on this\any platform would be of great help.

TIA

Comment: @Chandrulotstodo, I also want to help you download those packages, but I can't. Because my own subscription does not have such authority. In addition, MS sets these packages with high permissions to download them instead of opening them. I am not sure if there are any privacy or security issues, so I can't share them directly. You could contact to the PG team directly by posting a post in our main forum for product: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html

Comment: I have admin access in my subscription and still unable to access these nuget packages. So, even if I mark it as solution not sure if it will be of any use to common users like me. If u want me Accept as an answer I can do it. Let me know your thoughts.

Comment: @Chandrulotstodo, I can understand your concerns, but the solution to this problem is related to the permissions your subscription has. I'm sorry, I can't share these packages directly with you, you can temporarily mark this answer as an answer before you get better Before answering, so that ordinary users who have the same question over there can know that this question is related to their subscription.

Comment: Sure will mark it as an answer and request users to verify their permissions as well. Thanks for all the follow up and resolving my queries.